# Linux script to get the timestamp of the latest file from the FTP server's subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ftp, timestamp

I am new to linux and i can connect to the FTP server just fine.
I have backups running to ftp://test.test1.com to the directory /Backup/.

I need to connect to the server and scan the /Subdirectories to find the latest modified file and get the timestamp of it only.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Higher level scripting languages like Perl or Python are better suited for the task. Otherwise, most hosts also offer SSH which would allow you to run (for example) `find -ls` command directly.

Comment: I can run commands and connect to the ftp server via SSH(Putty) or Filezilla. I need to automate the everyday process of fetching latest modified file's timestamp and show on the xymon server. Scrtipting can be in any language Shell, Perl or phython

Comment: ssh can be used to run remote commands directly. So you can put the ssh command straight into a script. Assuming you have ssh  set up so that you don't need to enter a password then this command will get you the last modified file: ssh test.test1.com ls -lt /Backup | head -2 | tail -1. Once you get that you can parse the output further to get exactly what you want. And if you need to run this periodically, you can use cron to automate running of your script.